# Windows XP: is it possible to log startup and shutdown times in the system event log?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, logging, shutdown

Is it possible to log startup and shutdown times in Windows XP?
I mean logging these events in the system event log.

For example I can hack a jscript like this

```
// this is log_startup.js
var shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.LogEvent(0, "Startup timestamp = " + Date() );
```

and then adding it `cscript /nologo log_startup.js` to the startup menu folder but I would prefer a more Windows "native" way (and, by the way, I do not know how to detect the shutdown).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `gpedit.msc`, go to *Security Settings - Auditing*, enable auditing for system events (startup and shutdown). They will appear in the Security log.

Comment: +1 Thank you. I found the settings in gpedit.msc "Local Computer Policy","Computer Configuration","Windows Settings","Security Settings","Local Policies","Audit Policy","Audit system events". How can I configure the policy programmatically?

Comment: @uvts_cvs: Try the `auditusr` command. I'm not sure if there is any programmatic way to access the audit settings; best is to deploy the group policy over Active Directory.

Answer (score 4):

This information is already logged in the System Event Log.

```
Shutdown: Source = eventlog && Event ID = 6006
Startup: Source = eventlog && Event ID = 6009
```

If you need an approximate shutdown time in the event of an unexpected shutdown (e.g. BSOD or power loss), you'll need to use `uptime.exe` to enable the system heartbeat. It's available from [MS KB 232243](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232243).

In Vista/7, system heartbeat is enabled by default.  There are also more specific events that can be tracked.

```
Shutdown: Source = Kernel-General && Event ID = 13
Startup:  Source = Kernel-General && Event ID = 12
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems to me they are the start/stop of the event log facility, do they directly map to startup/shutdown of the machine?

Comment: Within a few seconds, yes. Event Log is one of the first things started and last to close. Ithas to be so that anything else can be reliably logged.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "hacking jscript" but...

Checkout this [MsGeek.com](http://www.msigeek.com/6231/how-to-enable-system-boot-time-logging-using-process-monitor-tool) article on how to "How To Enable System Boot Time Logging using Process Monitor Tool"